# Return large file as attachment from Extbase Controller action

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-11.x

In one of its actions, my Controller should return a large zip file, which I load from a cloud storage via curl before. It perfectly works with smaller files of 50MB or so, but throws an 500 error for large files of 1GB and aborts while sending files of 300MB or so. The files are completely present in the tmp folder.

This is what I return in my action:

`return $this->responseFactory->createResponse() ->withAddedHeader('Content-Type', 'application/zip') ->withAddedHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary') ->withAddedHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="submissionId.zip"') ->withAddedHeader('Content-Length', $length) ->withBody($this->streamFactory->createStream($content));`

I raised the memory_limit of the server to more than 2G, but nothing changed.

Comment: Please check the log file and post the reason for the 500 error.

Comment: `Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 977801216 bytes) in /usr/www/users/***/typo3_src-11.5.23/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Http/AbstractApplication.php on line 75`

Comment: `End of script output before headers`

Comment: Seems like your script needs about 3GB of memory and you allow only 2GB. You could try to set allowed_memory to 4GB. Just for a test. Normaly your script should not use that much memory. But maybe you then get a better error message.

Comment: No error message with 4G as memory_limit (or not so often), but the download still aborts before receiving the full file. Firefox (Ubuntu) saves the file and ends the download, Epiphany pauses the download and waits. Is there another way than using responseFactory and streamFactory?

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 11 i run a dynamic zip download for images. The file sizes also vary from 50MB to over 2GB.

I also struggled around with download aborts. This example does now run stable for several years since TYPO3 6. Although it is not implemented as described in the documentation.

```
public function downloadZipFile()    
{
    
    $zipTmpFile = tempnam("tmp", "zip");
    $zipArchive = new \ZipArchive();
    $zipArchive->open($this->zipTmpFile, \ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

    // .... adding files to the Zip archive
    // .... and create a download filename
    $downloadFileName = 'MyCoolZipFile';

    $this->zipArchive->close();
    ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Content-Type: application/zip, application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="' . $downloadFileName . '.zip"');
    header('Content-length: '.filesize($zipTmpFile));
    header('Cache-control: private');

    echo file_get_contents($zipTmpFile);
    unlink($zipTmpFile);
    exit();

}
```